# Micro USB Drive for use with Android smartphone

Tags: usb, android

I recently bought a [Moto X (second gen)](https://www.motorola.com/us/motomaker?pid=FLEXR2) Android smartphone. It came with 16 GB inbuilt storage, but no SD card slot. I still have a lot of storage left, but I can imagine myself running out in the future.

I know that Android devices can use micro USB drives as storage. I plan to use a USB drive for long-term storage, if possible.

I have looked on the internet for suitable USB drives, however most of the devices I have found are designed for short term use (i.e. file transfer). None of these are useful since they all protrue *out* of the smartphone where they can be easily damaged in everyday usage.

### Requirements

- Must interface via a micro-USB port
- Must not protrude out from the device any more than 5(ish) millimeters (i.e. must be suitable for leaving in the device over the long term)
- Must be at least 8 GB in size (but at least 16 is preferred)
- Must be compatible with Android Lollipop (this should be any USB device anyway)

---

A USB device similar to what I am looking for, is the [SanDisk Cruzer Fit](https://www.sandisk.com/home/usb-flash/cruzer-fit), but it only plugs into standard USB ports.

[image]

Comment: While they may exist, you will likely have trouble finding these - neither the software architecture of Android nor a typical phone's USB OTG capability is really designed to do this on a lasting basis, so issues ranging from poor integration with the OS in general, to no clear way to integrate with power management in a lastingly viable way, to micro USB connectors not having room for a circuit board to actually fit inside the socket in the way that full size USB "A" connectors do will likely lead to a disappointing experience and hence a lack of lasting market.